# Reset scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, sprite-kit, skscene

I have two different view controllers with a `SKScene` in the first one. There we find the game itself and in the second one the score with a "Replay" button. When the game finishes, I delete the scene and I `alloc`and `init` it again when the user clicks "Replay". My problem is that if a certain `SKSpriteNode` was rotated when the game ended, after deleting it and reseting it, when I go back to that scene it remains rotated in the exact same angle as before deleting the scene. The `-initWithSize` is called properly, so I'm not sure why is that happening. My question is if there's a way of resetting the `SKScene` so that it's identical to the first time the game was played. Thanks!

Comment: Put `NSLog` in Scene's `dealloc` method. It seems your scene is not deallocating.

Comment: You can simply reload the scene using `presentScene`

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I've just tried that and the `dealloc` method is being called.

Comment: @akashg I already do that when I'm in the second view controller and I want to go back to the game scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, create a method that creates the scene in the first place and recall it. If you have objects that are properties remove them from parent before recalling your scene creation method.

Example:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    [super initWithSize:size];
    [self startNewGame];
    return self;
}

-(void)startNewGame {
//all your scene configs here
}

-(void)buttonThatsCalledOnRestartClick {
   [self startNewGame];
}
```

the reason you're seeing your sprite in the same spot is because you're not removing it from the scene when you restart. Since you should probably just completely rebuild your scene you should remove all objects from scene and then call your "startNewGame" method again.

Example of removing all objects from scene:

```
for (SKNode* node in self.children) {
    [node removeFromParent];
}
```

Comment: You better use one compound layer for your scene and delete all child nodes with removeAllChildren method of SKNode class.